# JQuery SlideToggle-not responding

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".contentFAQ").hide();
  $(".headingFAQ").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".contentFAQ").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>


<p class = "headingFAQ">Question-1</p>
<div class = "contentFAQ">Answer-1</div>
<p class = "headingFAQ">Question-2</p>
<div class = "contentFAQ">Answer-2</div>
```

Hi All

Can someone please explain to me why the above code is not working. I took it from an old code and it still works on my old site, but on my new site on a different server it doesn't. I tried firebug but it gives no errors. I tried moving my jquery to the bottom of the page but still no nothing.

Comment: Are you including jQuery before the above?

Comment: Put some console.log(); Inside your code and see if it is actually reaching it. Maybe your jQuery lib is old or too new.

Comment: Your posted code works as expected. Whatever is your issue, it comes from somewhere else, maybe you didn't clear the cache or whatever

Comment: @Mooseman yes, I did

Comment: Sorry guys, there was a syntax error on the original, I corrected it here before posting but didn't do so on the original. That's just life lol